# how can i add feature map to the CNN before fullyConnectedLayer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

layers = [
imageInputLayer([width,height,channels]); %'DataAugmentation', 'none'); %'Normalization', 'none');
convolution2dLayer(2,16,'Padding',1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer
here add feature map
fullyConnectedLayer(12)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];

Comment: Please review how to format a post, explain your code, add details such as your deep-learning framework, maybe add some information on steps you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your dimensions of feature map(f1) should match the convolution layer output feature map(cf2)

Pytorch-torch.cat((f1,cf2), dim=1)
Tensorflow-tf.concat([t1, t2], axis=1)

NOTE:The output will have number of filters doubled[image]